# Creating a Trigger to change negative input values to positive values before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need to create a Trigger that checks `BEFORE INSERT`. For each row, if pc.price <= 0 then the price should be set to its absolute value

```
CREATE TRIGGER Neg_PC_Price
BEFORE INSERT ON PC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.price <= 0
    THEN ABS(NEW.price)
    END IF;
END;
```

This is what I pieced together from a different solution but instead of setting the new price they returned an error statement and not sure how to input with the updated positive price.

Comment: Your `ABS(NEW.price)` is hanging in the air - you have not told it what it must do with the result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the reason in additional and obviously excess IF statement. Simply

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Neg_PC_Price
BEFORE INSERT ON PC
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.price = ABS(NEW.price);
```